# MySQL SUM returns no rows should return 0

Tags: mysql, sum

There are no rows for this product_id. Result returns no rows instead of SUM = 0.

```
 SELECT COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) FROM store2product WHERE product_id = 6706434 GROUP BY product_id;
```

Is there a way to get result = 0?

Comment: Is `amount` definitely a numeric field? `COALESCE` will only return zero if `SUM` returns NULL, which presumably it is not.

Comment: amount is SMALLINT NOT NULL

Comment: Obviously you don’t get a record in the result set if there is no record that matches your WHERE clause. You'll need a JOIN or subquery of some sorts.

Comment: are you sure that the WHERE product_id = 6706434  return rows?

Comment: Good point @CBroe - I misread the question, if no rows are retrieved from the query, this is expected behaviour.

Comment: Remove group by

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no record for `product_id = 6706434` in table `store2product`. As you group by `product_id`, you get one result row per `product_id` found with this query. As the `product_id` is not found, no row is returned.

Simple solution: remove `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
  COALESCE(SUM(amount), 0) 
FROM store2product 
WHERE product_id = 6706434;
```

Now you get one result row in any case.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Trick..

Schema for your case

```
CREATE TABLE #TAB (ID INT, AMT DECIMAL(18,2))
INSERT INTO #TAB
SELECT 1,1200
UNION ALL
SELECT 1,120
UNION ALL 
SELECT 3, 100
```

Now query the table like

```
SELECT SUM(ISNULL(AMT,0)) AS AMT  FROM (

SELECT  ID, SUM(AMT)AMT FROM #TAB WHERE ID =2   GROUP BY ID
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL AS ID, NULL AS AMT

)A
```